# Increase the length of actionbutton in a shiny app

Tags: css, r, shiny

I would like to know how I could increase the length of an `actionbutton` in a `shiny` app.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  shinyUI(fluidPage(
    inputPanel(
      ## Original
      actionButton('button', 'Hi'),
      
      actionButton("optimize","Optimize", class = "run-button",
                   icon("paper-plane"), 
                   style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4")
    )
  )),
  shinyServer(function(input,output){})
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add width to your css

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  shinyUI(fluidPage(
    inputPanel(
      ## Original
      actionButton('button', 'Hi'),
      
      actionButton("optimize","Optimize", class = "run-button",
                   icon("paper-plane"), 
                   style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4; width:800px;")
    )
  )),
  shinyServer(function(input,output){})
)
```

Comment: thanks do u know how can I align its label title left as well?

Comment: Sure, just add text-align: left; to the css